# Cannot upload a photos (channel images) when using Channel Form

Tags: safecracker, channel-images

I am using channel form to create a new entry in my gallery and use {field:gallery_images} to display the channel images field.

On the form when I try and click on the upload images button nothing happens.

```
{exp:clubmanager:club}   
                     {exp:channel:form channel="gallery" return="clubhouse/gallery" class="sky-form" }
                        <input type="hidden" name="gallery_club" value="{club_name}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="gallery_club_url" value="{club_url_title}">
                    <fieldset>   
                      <section>
                            <label class="label">Title</label>
                            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" size="50" maxlength="100" onkeyup="liveUrlTitle();">
                            <input type="hidden" name="url_title" id="url_title" value="{url_title}" maxlength="75" size="50">
                        </section>

                         </fieldset>

                           <fieldset>  
                            <section>
                            <label class="label">Images</label>
                                {field:gallery_images}
                            </section>

                            </fieldset>  

                            <footer>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn-u">Submit</button>
                            </footer>
                        {/exp:channel:form}
                        <!-- End Publish Report Form-->

             {/exp:clubmanager:club}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not at a computer but it sounds like you are missing the JavaScript file needed to make it work. Use Show-EE submit form as an example.

Comment: Meant to reply earlier, came across an older post that removing your own js would solve the problem. So I stopped loading js in the template and it works fine now.